# How can one find the adb's binary to program an app in AndroidStudio?

Tags: adb, device

Every time I try to run my app there opens a window saying "System UI isn't respondind". I've read here that this has sth to do with the avd which can't detect the ADB binary. So I should change the Setting "Use detected ADB location" and set it off. Then I should add the location of the adb binary.

[Could not automatically detect an ADB binary - Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617997/could-not-automatically-detect-an-adb-binary-android-studio/43064441#43064441)

But I don't know how to get this location. So does anybody know how one can get the adb binary location?

I also don't know what the adb binary is at all...so it would also be nice if sb could explain it to me or give me helpful links.

Katharina Hohenfels

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidStudio - File - Settings - Appearance & Behavior - System Settings - Android SDK, choose 'SDK Tools' tab, tick 'Android SDK Platform-Tools' - Apply