# Android Studio 4.0 doesn't recognize any previous virtual devices

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

First post--be gentle. Can't find any posts on Android Studio 4.0, so I hope this isn't a repeat. I updated Android Studio from 3.6.3 to 4.0 on Windows 10 (1909). Had created a couple of virtual devices in 3.6.3 (a Pixel 2 running API 28 and a Pixel 3 running API 29)--both worked great in AS-3.6.3 and I could develop apps, compile, load, and run them with no problem.

After the update to AS-4.0, the virtual devices no longer appear in the devices box at the top of the GUI--it just says "No Devices". When I open the AVD Manager, I can see them, and I can start them (although when I start them I get a pop-up saying "AVD Manager: Unable to locate adb"), but I can't get any code to download and execute on it. On the Pixel 3 emulator, I also get another pop-up saying "Detected ADB: Could not automatically detect an ADB binary.", and it gives instructions to resolve it, which don't make any difference (jump into extended controls and toggle "Use detected ADB location").

When I try to open a past project and run it, I get the same behavior--no devices found.

I've also tried making new emulators, hoping the new setup would recognize them, but to no avail. Tried starting and restarting AS, as well as the computer, also to no avail. I have Android SDK Build-Tools 30-rc4, the latest Android SDK Command-line Tools, Android Emulator 30.0.12 Android SDK Platform-Tools 30.0.1, and the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator all installed.

I've Googled and spoken words of fierce power over this for several days now. Any suggestions for how to get AS-4.0 to recognize the emulators? I've resisted uninstalling everything and starting over--was hoping it was just a configuration thing.

Thanks in advance,
Uber

Answer (score 0):

After some more Googling, I found the answer here (I think my constraint of wanting an answer for AS-4.0 specifically kept me from finding it):

[Could not automatically detect an ADB binary - Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617997/could-not-automatically-detect-an-adb-binary-android-studio)

I had to redownload the SDK platform-tools zip file and reinstall it. I don't know why the old one got messed up with the migration from AS-3.6.3 to 4.0, but there you go--such is life with complicated software.

As soon as I replaced the old platform-tools directory with the new one, all my old emulators showed up and I was back in business.

Thanks anyway!
Uber