# Android. How from command line start emulator, deploy apk AND run apk?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Windows 10 (64 bit).

My emulator is locate on folder :

d:\Programs\Android\avd.android\avd\Nexus_4_4.avd\

My apk is locate on folder:

d:\Programs\Android\apk\my_apk.apk

I'm locate on folder **D:\temp**
If I want to start emulator from command line (prompt) I use the next command:

```
emulator -avd exus_4_4.avd
```

It's work fine. Emulator is success launched.

But I need more. Only from command line:

1. Launch emulator
2. Deploy d:\Programs\Android\apk\my_apk.apk to started emulator
3. Run apk on emulator

How I can do this from command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you install an APK file in the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install a .apk file you need follow the below steps

- Open the command prompt inside `d:\Programs\Android\apk\`
- Type `adb install my_apk.apk` and press Enter.
- If the app is already installed in the device then use `adb install -r FileName.apk`

Answer (score 1):

Check Android developer site for this kind of information.
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html

Install

```
adb install path/to/your_app.apk
```

and install with run

```
adb -d install path/to/your_app.apk
```