# Cannot find FBAndroid.apk as per Facebook Android SDK docs

Tags: xamarin, android-emulator, visual-studio-emulator

I am trying to use, [Facebook Android SDK](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/facebookandroid) (Xamarin Component) in Visual Studio 2017. The chosen emulator is,

[image: VS Emulator used]

I downloaded the SDK as per the Xamarin documents,

> To take advantage of the native Facebook dialogs, the Facebook
>   application must be installed on the device. If the Facebook
>   application is not installed on the device, fallbacks to Web based
>   dialogs can instead be used. If you are testing on an emulator which
>   does not have the ability to install Facebook from the Play store, **you
>   can install FBAndroid.apk which is included in the SDK** which can be
>   downloaded from:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads

The problem is, I don't see any FBAndroid.apk inside the zipped SDK file.

The questions are,

1. Is my understanding correct about the installation?
2. If so, from where would I find the apk to install in my emulator?

Edit: Installing an APK is not my concern now, I am worried about this part.

> install FBAndroid.apk which is included in the SDK

P.S: Edited the title to reflect the change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you install an APK file in the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator)

Comment: Not at all. 1. Is the Xamarin tutorial correct? 2. Where to find fbandroid.apk. I know how to install an apk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That section of the Xamarin doc is *outdated*. The Facebook APK is has not been available as a separate download since the v3 version of the SDK (circa 2015).

If you look under the `Facebook SDK for Android v3.x Downloads` section of the [SDK Downloads](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads) you will find old `FBAndroid.apk` versions available for separate download.

If your emulator does not have the Play Store installed (Genymotion?), install it via [OpenGApps](http://opengapps.org) and then install Facebook from the PlayStore.

Comment: Thanks. Heard genymotion is good. Does it have an open-source alternative?

Comment: @naveen There is the `Android-x86 Open Source Project`  (http://www.android-x86.org) but it is not providing **Android device emulation** but an Android version that runs on x86. For device emulation the official Google Android emulator is the way to go as they provide x86/x86_64 images that already include all the Google Apps preinstalled and with Intel HAXM acceleration the emulators can run as fast as devices (assuming the host is a modern PC)