# Apache Cordova apk is invalid

Tags: android, apk, apache-cordova

In Visual Studio I have generated an apk file following [these instructions](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/).

Then I want to install the apk like it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator), and adb install gives the error "INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK", without any more details.

I have searched a lot and tried many things, in config.xml I put version code = 100, min api version = 14, max api version = 26, target api = 23. What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to solve this problem was to use a newer version of Android device. In this way when generating the apk in Visual Studio the apk is no more invalid.